# How long does Google Play Store take to update install count

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the Play Store. I recently completed 500 downloads of the app. The Google Play Developer Console is showing 525 installs as of 2 days ago (29th May):

[image: Play Console Stats]

So, the data is already 2 days old. But on the play store, it still shows `100-500` in the Installs section:

[image: Play Store Stats]

If it is already updated in the `Play Developer Console`, then it should be updated in the Play Store. So, my question is, how long does the play store take to update this stat?

**Update**

It got updated. I guess I was just being impatient :)

Comment: It took me approx 12 days to get it updated in play store, once it reached 50k in my developer console

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The count of installs on your app page is rounded up (or for better understanding milestone based). As and when you reach thresholds the displayed count changes.

You have crossed 500 now so it shows 500. Your next milestone is 1000. Once you cross 1000 downloads the number on your app page on play store will show `1000 downloads`. There after 5k, 10k, 50k, 100k, 500k, 1M and so on.

Also the updates take time and are not instantaneous. It may sometimes take over a week and sometimes just a day. Depends on when google's data processing jobs to update the statistics executes.

Comment: That I am aware of Sir. But when the downloads have crossed 500, it should be showing 500-1000, shouldn't it?

Comment: the update takes time and is not instantaneous. Sometimes in my case it took over a week to reflect.

Comment: oh really? That is a lot of time :/
Anyways, thank you for the info! :)

Comment: I think 10k does not exist because i well passed 15k downloads since several weeks, still my app is showing the 5k publicly

Comment: @EzequielAdrian 10k definitely exists.

Comment: Is this number, downloads or currently installed devices?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently so I contacted Google Play developers support and they clarified the issue.

The number shown in Developer's console statistics "New users acquired" and on the "Installs" badge in Google Play are computed using different algorithms. The first one shows raw installs while the second one shows the somehow corrected data. In particular, install metrics may be discounted or even removed entirely if Google detects fraudulent installs.