# Is there any criteria for Google Play Store to update app installs count?

Tags: google-play

My App crossed 100000 downloads 3 days back but on Play Store still it says 50000 downloads. How long does Google Play Store takes to display app install count ? Is there any criteria for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does Google Play Store take to update install count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538473/how-long-does-google-play-store-take-to-update-install-count)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such criteria

It takes some time to update the statistics in play store , i also faced some problem for my app.

i launched this app yesterday still there is no download updated in Google play console but it has been downloaded by 50+ people.