# How often does Google play update the stats for users?

Tags: android, google-play

A week ago my Google developer console showed I reached 100k downloads yet the google play store only shows 50k+. How often does it update those external facing download stats for users to see? There are some other apps showing 100k+ so I figure that is the next value shown in google play store catalog for an app after 50k+.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does Google Play Store take to update install count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538473/how-long-does-google-play-store-take-to-update-install-count)

Comment: I talked to someone at Google Play Store help and they said they felt the count was inflated so they will wait for awhile. I also noted the overall total download count in the stats stopped increasing although the downloads continued. This was after several weeks. Very unusual. I am hoping you are right!